# Make t i m e equal 14 39 55 58

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I'm bored of those number challenges. I know we can be more creative. We're puzzling, not mathematics. I've given you enough information to solve this problem.

> How can you make t i m e = 14 39 55 58?

Comment: 20, 9, 13, 5 is the numbers that are t i m e

Comment: I assume it works respectively; i.e., $t=14$, $i=39$, $m=55$ and $e=58$.... but you can never be too sure with enigmatic-puzzles... @Duck that is just letting $A=1$, $B=2$, etc.

Comment: I don't don't know what the 'e' stands for, but I am sure Tim won't be happy that you have publicly displayed his phone number.

Comment: @tox123 would "T I M E" make a difference or is it specifically "t i m e"? :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I'm not case sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting on this  t i m e = 14 39 55 58, i f (=1 12) we consider the question:

> I'm bored of **t**hose number challenges. **I** know we can be **m**or**e**...
>
>  the first **t** = position 14,
>  the next **i** = position 39,
>  the next **m** = position 56  (just off-by-one from 55),
>  the next **e** = position 59  (similarly one above 58).